# Associate NSFetchedResultsController with specific section in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I've got a UITableView that needs to display two sets of search results, with each set of search results being a different entity.

Each entity needs to display its search results in a specific section.  I need to use an NSFetchResultsController so that if additional data becomes available the tableview automatically updates.

My question is, how do I associate a specific NSFetchedResultsController with a specific section? By this I mean I want all of the fetch results for entity 1 to be in section 0, while all of the search fetch results from entity 2 to be in section 1 of the tableview.

I've no problem having a tableview with a single section / single fetch controller, but is there anyway to have an NSFetchedResultsController be associated with a specific section of the table view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you set up the two `NSFetchedResultsController`s, in the number of sections delegate method, specify 2 sections, for the delegate method for number of rows in a section, look at the section number and get the count from the appropriate fetched results controller, and in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, get the data from the appropriate fetched results controller based on the section number in the index path.

Comment: Thanks - though I'm wondering how this will work in terms of the delegate protocol in terms of the change callbacks? I.e. insert / delete / change?

Comment: You will need to change the logic to deal with the proper section based on which `NSFetchedResultsController` you're dealing with at the time. So anywhere that you're interacting with an `NSFetchedResultsController`, you'll need to add some logic. But it shouldn't be too hard to set this up. If you have a working implementation with 1 fetched results controller, you should be able to expand it to 2 without too much trouble.